# A HREF issue can’t fix it

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I need fix this problem I have more `<a>` attr. and when click on different I’ll get same webpage I think about that and issue is in jQuery code

```
var socialIcons = $(".social a"),
   href = socialIcons.attr("href");

socialIcons.on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function() { 
           window.location.href = href;
     }, 500);
});
```

Comment: How many of `.social a` do you have?

Comment: I have 5 links for .social a

Comment: Which is why it is not working, see the answer by Barmar

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `href` to the attribute of the first element that matches the selector when the page is loaded, not the one that the user has actually clicked on. You need to set the variable in the callback function, and make it related to the clicked element (which is `this` in the handler function).

```
socialIcons.on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href;
     }, 500);
});
```

Comment: many thanks now its working, and in html code is target set to _blank but now is window opened on the same page how to fix it in jquery ? thx

Comment: Use `window.open()` instead of `window.location.href =`